# A closed space is the kernel of some map

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

I'm working on the following problems in Royden:

> Let $X_0$ be a codimension 1 subspace of a normed linear space $X$. Show that $X_0$ is closed with respect to the strong topology if and only if the $X_0$ = $\ker \phi $ for some $\phi \in X^*$

The reverse direction is clear -- continuous functions pull back closed sets. The forward direction I'm a bit unsure of -- I set up a function: $$\phi: X_0 \mapsto 0 \\ a + X_0 \mapsto a$$
I show then that its well defined, linear, and continuous -- and so sits in $X^*$. Is there an easier way see this without explicitly exhibiting a map? I haven't really used the fact that the maps was co-dimension 1. My construction works for any codimension of $X_0$, which is leading me to doubt my method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X_0$ is closed.  Since $X_0$ is a proper subspace, there is some nonzero linear functional $\phi\in X^*$ such that $X_0\subset\ker\phi$ (by the Hahn-Banach theorem).  Suppose the inclusion is strict.  Then there is some $x\in \ker\phi\setminus X_0$.  But $X=X_0\oplus\text{span}\{x\}$, so $X=\ker\phi$, a contradiction, and therefore $X_0=\ker\phi$.

Comment: don't we need some dominating function for hahn-banach? what are you verifying in the second part of this statement ("i.e. after Suppose the inclusion is strict..."). I don't follow what you're doing.

Comment: No, we're using the corollary to the Hahn-Banach theorem that if $Y$ is a normed space (or more generally a locally convex space), $X$ a closed subspace, and $y\in Y\setminus X$, there is some $f\in Y^*$ with $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in X$ and $f(y)\neq0$.

Comment: In the second part, we know $X_0\subset\ker\phi$, and we want $X_0=\ker\phi$ to complete the theorem.  So we assume the inclusion is strict and look for a contradiction (this is where the fact that $X_0$ is of codimension $1$ comes in).

Comment: I was looking for the proof of this corollary. I found a proof that just produced a functional explicitly -- $d(y,X)$ where $d$ is the distance from $y \in X^c$ ($X^c$ is complement of $X$ in $Y$) to the set $X$. This takes $0$ when if $y\in X$. I didn't see any mention of Hahn Banch though. Is this equivalent to the corollary you mention. If not, can you point me in the direction of a reference that contains a proof of that statement? (Or sketch an argument)

Comment: A proof can be found in chapter 3 of Rudin's functional analysis book (and I imagine most books on the subject contain the theorem in some form) shortly after proving the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: And my problem with the proof you mention is that the functional you mention is not linear.